# How can I convert a static array into a persistent list in room?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I want to convert a static array of object into a persitent list inside my room database, to use it in a spinner.

```
@Entity(tableName = "task_table")
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "projectId")
    private long projectId;

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    // Suppress warning because setName is called in constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @ColumnInfo(name = "creationTimestamp")
    private long creationTimestamp;

    public long getCreationTimestamp() {
        return creationTimestamp;
    }

    public Task(long projectId, @NonNull String name, long creationTimestamp) {
        this.setProjectId(projectId);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCreationTimestamp(creationTimestamp);
    }
```

This is the main object that is showed in my main activity. It uses the object that I want to put in my database. The other object is a Project, here projectId.

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = Task.class,
        parentColumns = "p_projectId",
        childColumns = "projectId",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
})
public class Project {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_projectId")
    private final long projectId;

    @NonNull
    private final String name;

    @ColorInt
    private final int color;

    private Project(long projectId, @NonNull String name, @ColorInt int color) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @NonNull
    public static Project[] getAllProjects() {
        return new Project[]{
                new Project(1L, "Project 1", 0xFFEADAD1),
                new Project(2L, "Project 2", 0xFFB4CDBA),
                new Project(3L, "Project 3", 0xFFA3CED2),
        };
    }
```

And this is the list of objects that I need to be persistent in my database, and that I need to show in a spinner when we have to add a task.

This is the code related to the room db.

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class}, version = 4, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class TaskDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static TaskDatabase database;

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "TODOC_database";

    public synchronized static TaskDatabase getInstance(Context context){
     if (database == null) {
         database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                 TaskDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                 .allowMainThreadQueries()
                 .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                 .build();
     }
     return database;
    }

    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();
}
```

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table")
    List<Task> getAll();

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(Task task);

    @Delete
    void delete(Task task);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert a static array into a persistent list in room?

I believe that the following does what you want.

It's a working example and includes examples of suggested changes and additions. Hopefully the comments will describe the changes and additions

So starting with the **SLIGHTLY CHANGED**, **Task Entity** (aka task_table) :-

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "task_table",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Project.class,
                        parentColumns = "p_projectId",
                        childColumns = "projectId",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
        /*
            As Task references a Project the Task is the child so Foreign Key definition is here not in Project
         */
)
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(name = "projectId", index = true) // ROOM warns of FK not indexed so added and index
    private long projectId;

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    // Suppress warning because setName is called in constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(name = "creationTimestamp")
    private long creationTimestamp;

    public long getCreationTimestamp() {
        return creationTimestamp;
    }

    public Task(long projectId, @NonNull String name, long creationTimestamp) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.name = name;
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
    }
}
```

- Note see **Project** for suggested way to code SQLite item names, these suggestions have not been applied to Task.
- Main change is to define:-

  - The Foreign Key (instead of in **Project**)
  - An index on the FK column (Room warns if not coded)

The **DRASTICALLY CHANGED**, **Project** Entity :-

```
@Entity (/*foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = Task.class,
        parentColumns = "p_projectId",
        childColumns = "projectId",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    },*/
        tableName = Project.TABLE_NAME
)
    // Foreign key should be in Task as a Task is a child to one of the projects

public class Project {

    /* The defined projects */
    public static final Project[] DEFINED_PROJECTS = {
            new Project(1L, "Project 1", 0xFFEADAD1),
            new Project(2L, "Project 2", 0xFFB4CDBA),
            new Project(3L, "Project 3", 0xFFA3CED2)
    };

    /* Suggest always having a single source for DB items (tables columns etc) */
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "project";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN_NAME = "p_projectId";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN_NAME = "name"; //<<<<< not the wisest choice of column name as is an SQLite KEYWORD
    public static final String COLOR_COLUMN_NAME = "color";
    public static final String PREFIX = "_project_"; //<<<<< used for disambiguating like name column names

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    private long projectId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = NAME_COLUMN_NAME)
    private String name;

    @ColorInt
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLOR_COLUMN_NAME)
    private int color;

    private Project(long projectId, @NonNull String name, @ColorInt int color) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Project(){}

    /* NOT NEEDED here see DEFINED_PROJECTS above
    @NonNull
    public static Project[] getAllProjects() {
        return new Project[]{
                new Project(1L, "Project 1", 0xFFEADAD1),
                new Project(2L, "Project 2", 0xFFB4CDBA),
                new Project(3L, "Project 3", 0xFFA3CED2),
        };
    }
    */

    public void setProjectId(long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

- Quite a few changes, see the comments

A **NEW** POJO **TaskWithProject** to combine a task with it's project (which you will probably want) :-

```
/*
    Embeds both Entities uses prefix to disambiguate columns
        SEE @Query
        Could use @Relation instead but it's not really meant for 1-1
 */
public class TaskWithProject {
    @Embedded
    Task task;
    @Embedded(prefix = Project.PREFIX)
    Project project;
}
```

A **NEW** Dao for inserting/deleting/retrieving Projects **ProjectDao** :-

```
@Dao
interface ProjectDao {
    @Insert
    long[] insert(List<Project> projects);
    @Insert
    long insert(Project project);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Project.TABLE_NAME)
    List<Project> getAllProjects();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Project.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Project.ID_COLUMN_NAME + "=:projectId")
    Project getProjectById(long projectId);
}
```

- Note how all SQLite names are using the variables defined
- Note you could include the above within the TaskDao instead of having a separate ProjectDao

A **CHANGED**, **TaskDao** (i.e. the new Query to get Task's with the respective Project):-

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table")
    List<Task> getAll();

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(Task task);

    @Delete
    void delete(Task task);

    /*
        <<<<<ADDED>>>>> to get All Tasks with the Project
    */
    @Query("SELECT task_table.*," +
            Project.TABLE_NAME +"." + Project.ID_COLUMN_NAME +" AS " + Project.PREFIX + Project.ID_COLUMN_NAME + "," +
            Project.TABLE_NAME +"." + Project.NAME_COLUMN_NAME + " AS " + Project.PREFIX + Project.NAME_COLUMN_NAME + ", " +
            Project.TABLE_NAME +"." + Project.COLOR_COLUMN_NAME + " AS " + Project.PREFIX + Project.COLOR_COLUMN_NAME + " " +
            "FROM task_table " +
            "JOIN " + Project.TABLE_NAME + " ON task_table.projectId = " + Project.TABLE_NAME + "." + Project.ID_COLUMN_NAME + ";"
    )
    /* equates to
        SELECT task_table.*, project.p_projectId AS _project_p_projectId, project.name AS _project_name, project.color AS _project_color
        FROM task_table JOIN project ON task_table.projectId = project.p_projectId;

        i.e. the project columns expected due to the prefix = "_project_" coded in the the @Embedded  should be :-
            _project_p_projectId
            _project_name (the ambiguous column as task_table has name column as well as project having name column)
            _project_color
     */
    List<TaskWithProject> getAllTasksWithProjects();
}
```

The **DRASTICALLY CHANGED** (added to) @Database **TaskDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities =
        {
                Task.class,
                Project.class /* <<<<<ADDED>>>>> */
        },
        version = 4,
        exportSchema = false
)
public abstract class TaskDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static TaskDatabase database;

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "TODOC_database";

    public synchronized static TaskDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (database == null) {
            database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    TaskDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(CALLBACK) //<<<<< ADDED
                    .build();
        }
        return database;
    }

    /*
      ADDED to allow population of the defined projects
     */
    public static Callback CALLBACK = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            initialiseProjects(db); //<<<<< Here?
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            /* Here? always checks that correct number of projects exist
             * Most flexible option but least efficient
             * i.e. Called whenever DB is opened
             * doesn't need DB version change to introduce changed projects as
             * adding new project with new APK will cause new project to be loaded
             */
            Cursor csr = db.query("SELECT count(*) FROM " + Project.TABLE_NAME);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                long row_count = csr.getLong(0);
                if (row_count != Project.DEFINED_PROJECTS.length) initialiseProjects(db);
            }
            csr.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestructiveMigration(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
            initialiseProjects(db); //<<<<< or Here?
        }
    };

    /*
        DELETES ANY EXISTING AND ADDS ALL PROJECTS
        Can be called from many places as shown above
     */
    private static void initialiseProjects(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        boolean alreadyInTransaction = db.inTransaction();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (!alreadyInTransaction) db.beginTransaction();
        db.delete(Project.TABLE_NAME,null,null);
        for(Project p: Project.DEFINED_PROJECTS) {
            cv.clear();
            cv.put(Project.ID_COLUMN_NAME,p.getProjectId());
            cv.put(Project.NAME_COLUMN_NAME,p.getName());
            cv.put(Project.COLOR_COLUMN_NAME,p.getColor());
            db.insert(Project.TABLE_NAME, OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE,cv);
        }
        if (!alreadyInTransaction) {
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();
    public abstract ProjectDao projectDao(); //<<<<< ADDED
}
```

Finally putting it all together in an invoking activity **MainActivity** which gets the List for the Spinner :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TaskDatabase db;
    TaskDao taskDao;
    ProjectDao projectDao;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        /* Get the database and dao's */
        db = TaskDatabase.getInstance(this);
        taskDao = db.taskDao();
        projectDao = db.projectDao();

        /* Add some test Tasks to prove all working */
        taskDao.insert(new Task(1,"Task1", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        taskDao.insert(new Task(2,"Task2", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        
        /* Get the Projects for the Spinner */
        List<Project> mySpinnerSourceArray = projectDao.getAllProjects(); //<<<<< SOURCE FOR SPINNER
        for (Project p: mySpinnerSourceArray) {
            Log.d("SPINNERDATA","Project ID = " + p.getProjectId() + " Name = " + p.getName() + " color = " + p.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

**1. First App install/run** :-

When run the output to the log is (aka the data available for the spinner) :-

```
2021-06-24 12:14:27.397 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 1 Name = Project 1 color = -1385775
2021-06-24 12:14:27.397 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 2 Name = Project 2 color = -4928070
2021-06-24 12:14:27.397 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 3 Name = Project 3 color = -6041902
```

The database (using Android Studio's Database Inspector) :-

The **Project** table :-

[image]

The **Task** table :-

[image]

**2. Second run (just rerun so will create addition Tasks, Projects should remain as they are)** :-

Log is :-

```
2021-06-24 12:21:30.978 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 1 Name = Project 1 color = -1385775
2021-06-24 12:21:30.978 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 2 Name = Project 2 color = -4928070
2021-06-24 12:21:30.978 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 3 Name = Project 3 color = -6041902
```

The **Project** table :-

[image]

The **Task** table :-

[image]

**3. Changed the DEFINED PROJECTS (added 1)** :-

i.e. by just changing the code to be :-

```
/* The defined projects */
public static final Project[] DEFINED_PROJECTS = {
        new Project(1L, "Project 1", 0xFFEADAD1),
        new Project(2L, "Project 2", 0xFFB4CDBA),
        new Project(3L, "Project 3", 0xFFA3CED2),
        new Project(100L,"MY NEW PROJECT",0xFFAABBCC)
};
```

- **no change to db version it is still 4.** but effectively distributing a new APK :-

the Log is :-

```
2021-06-24 12:30:16.349 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 1 Name = Project 1 color = -1385775
2021-06-24 12:30:16.349 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 2 Name = Project 2 color = -4928070
2021-06-24 12:30:16.349 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 3 Name = Project 3 color = -6041902
2021-06-24 12:30:16.350 D/SPINNERDATA: Project ID = 100 Name = MY NEW PROJECT color = -5588020
```

- Note the code above will not detect a changed project only added or removed. However if a destructive migration is encountered then all projects will be reapplied.

Comment: It works as intended, thank you so much !

Comment: @UmiRuZa if you believe that the answer helped you then please tick it as the answer.